# Installed with Windows authentication but dont know the SQL server UID & PW

Tags: sql-server, logins

i have installed SQL express without providing any user ID or password, ie. with Windows Authentication, now i want to login using SQL Authentication UID & PW, but i dont know what is my UID &PW

I tried all suggestion of changing as in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBM9JyrIPBI

https://www.top-password.com/knowledge/change-sql-server-password.html

How do I know what is my default UID & Password ( sa & sa is not working )

Comment: Does loging in with Windows user work?

Answer (score 0):

When installing SQL Express, the windows user who was running the installer is by default added as the sysadmin role.

Unless you specify the security mode of `SQL` during the install and a password for `SAPWD`, only Windows Authentication will be enabled by default. So only logging in via Windows Authentication is supported initially.

To login with SQL Authentication, you'll need to [enable it first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-2017), then change the `sa` password / create a new login (you shouldn't be using the `sa` login 99.99% of the time) so you can login using it.

Once you've done this, you should be able to follow the youtube video you linked to with the crendentials you used to create a  new login / alter the `sa` login.

Resources:

- I wrote an article on the [Unattended Install of SQL Server Express](http://expressdb.io/sql-server-express-unattended-install/#2016-2017-unattended-install) that covers using `SecurityMode` and `SAPWD` during install to create a default SA SQL auth login.